# How do I separate data into different variable in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hey guys I am have an data that looks like this [train.dat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvmB6.png) . I am trying to create an varible that will contain the [ith] value of the column containing(-1,or 1), and another variable to hold the value of column that have strings.

So far I have tried this,

```
  df=pd.read_csv("train.dat",delimiter="\t", sep=',')
# print(df.head())


# separate names from classes
vals = df.ix[:,:].values
names = [n[0][3:] for n in vals]
cls = [n[0][0:] for n in vals]
print(cls)
```

**However the output looks all jumbled up, any help would be appreciated. I am a begineer in python**

Comment: Please post a sample of your data as text, not an image.

Answer (score 1):

If the character after the numerical value is a tab, you're fine and all you would need is

```python
import io # using io.StringIO for demonstration
import pandas as pd

ratings = "-1\tThis movie really sucks.\n-1\tRun colored water through 
a reflux condenser and call it a science movie?\n+1\tJust another zombie flick? You'll be surprised!"

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(ratings), sep='\t', 
                 header=None, names=['change', 'rating'])
```

- Passing `header=None` makes sure that the first line is interpreted as data.
- Passing `names=['change', 'rating']` provides some (reasonable) column headers.

Of course, the character is not a tab :D.

```python
import io # using io.string
import pandas as pd

ratings = "-1 This movie really sucks.\n-1 Run colored water through a 
reflux condenser and call it a science movie?\n+1 Just another zombie 
flick? You'll be surprised!"

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(ratings), sep='\t', 
                 header=None, names=['stuff'])

df['change'], df['rating'] = df.stuff.str[:3], df.stuff.str[3:] 
df.drop('stuff', axis=1)
```

One viable option is to read in the whole rating as one temporary column, split the string, distribute it to two columns and eventually drop the temporary column.